# how to create rich:dropDownMenu dynamically using c:foreach?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jstl

I wanted to populate a dropdowm menu dynamically, so i used `<c:forEach>` but i'm not able see the data in the frontend.

**My JSF**

```
<rich:dropDownMenu id="drop_down" value="Add"
            direction="bottom-right" jointPoint="auto">
            <c:forEach var="item" items="#{library.addLeftPanel}" >
                <rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" value="#{item}"
                    actionListener="#{library.populateCBConditions}"
                    reRender="tree_comp, filtab" />
            </c:forEach>

</rich:dropDownMenu>
```

**My Managed Bean**

```
  private List<String> addLeftPanel;   


  /**
 * @param addLeftPanel
 *            the addLeftPanel to set
 */
public void setAddLeftPanel(List<String> addLeftPanel) {
    this.addLeftPanel = addLeftPanel;
}

/**
 * @return the addLeftPanel
 */
public List<String> getAddLeftPanel() {
    if(null==addLeftPanel){
            addLeftPanel = new ArrayList<String>();
    addLeftPanel.add("First");
    addLeftPanel.add("Secound");
    }
    return addLeftPanel;
}
```

I'm using JSF 1.1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/01/creating-richdropdownmenu-dynamically/

Comment: I created a normal code for <c:forEach>, like in the same above code, i tried to print the to put <h:outputText>, but the text is not getting printed. Is there any restriction of JSTL versions for <c:forEach>. Actually i started with the link provided above only.

Comment: What namespace do you use for JSTL? Do you use JSP or Facelets?

Comment: Also, make sure you use the latest JSTL Jar version.

Comment: thanks, i resolved the issue. There was some issue with the List which i was using, when i used another one it was working.